# Converting Java to Objective-c (Android to iOS)

Tags: java, objective-c, ios, xcode

**EDIT: this is the corrected version of the converted code**

```
int scrambBase20[] = {1,2,3};
- (NSString *) descramble:(NSString*) input{
    char *ret = [input UTF8String];
    int offset = -(sizeof scrambBase20);
    for(int i=0;i<[input length];i++){
        if(i%(sizeof scrambBase20)==0){
            offset+=(sizeof scrambBase20);
        }
        ret[scrambBase20[i%(sizeof scrambBase20)]+offset] = (char) ((Byte) [input characterAtIndex:i]^0x45);
    }
    NSString *realRet = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:ret];
    [realRet stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    return realRet;
}
```

I have this block of Java which I am trying to convert to Objective-C.

I have an encrypted string which I am trying to decrypt.

```
[descramble: @"6&eee *eee1ee1e eee!"];
```

Should become

```
"testcode" (without quotes)
```

Instead, I get the output

```
"6&sec *ee 1ee1e  ee!" (without quotes)
```

The following code is my Java code [works]

```
String descramble(String input){
    Log.i("APP", "input length: " + input.length());
    char[] ret; //= new ArrayList<Character>();
    ret = input.toCharArray();
    int offset = -scrambBase20.length;
    for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
        if(i%scrambBase20.length==0)
            offset+=scrambBase20.length;
        ret[scrambBase20[i%scrambBase20.length]+offset]=(char) ((byte) (input.charAt(i))^0x45);
    }

    String realRet = "";
    for (char x : ret){
        realRet+=x;
    }
    realRet = realRet.trim();
    return realRet;
}
```

The following code is my converted code to Xcode [doesn't work]

```
- (NSString *) descramble:(NSString*) input{
   char *ret = [input UTF8String];
   int offset = -(sizeof scrambBase20);
   for(int i=0;i<(sizeof input);i++){
        if(i%(sizeof scrambBase20)==0){
            offset+=(sizeof scrambBase20);
        }
        ret[scrambBase20[i%(sizeof scrambBase20)]+offset] = (char) ((Byte) [input characterAtIndex:i]^0x45);
    }
    NSString *realRet = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:ret];
    [realRet stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    return realRet;
}
```

Does anyone see an error in the conversion from Java to Objective-C?

Comment: What is `scrambBase20`? NSString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `scrambBase20` is an array, you need to use `count` instead of `sizeOf`. Objective C equivalent of `sizeOf()` in Java is `count`.

```
- (NSString *) descramble:(NSString*) input{
   char *ret = [input UTF8String];
   int offset = (-1 * [scrambBase20 count]);
   for(int i=0;i<[input length];i++){
        if(i% [scrambBase20 count] == 0){
            offset+= [scrambBase20 count];
        }
        ret[scrambBase20[i%[scrambBase20 count]+offset] = (char) ((Byte) [input characterAtIndex:i]^0x45);
    }
    NSString *realRet = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:ret];
    [realRet stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    return realRet;
}
```

For an `NSString`, equivalent of `length()` in java to objective c is `[string length]`. For `cString`, it is `strlen()`.

**Update:**

As per your edit, it is a C array and not NSArray. In that case you need to use,

```
- (NSString *) descramble:(NSString*) input{
    char *ret = [input UTF8String];
    int offset = -1 * ((sizeof scrambBase20) / (sizeof int));
    for(int i=0;i < [input length];i++){
        if(i%((sizeof scrambBase20) / (sizeof int))==0){
            offset+=((sizeof scrambBase20) / (sizeof int));
        }
        ret[scrambBase20[i%((sizeof scrambBase20) / (sizeof int))]+offset] = (char) ((Byte) [input characterAtIndex:i]^0x45);
    }
    NSString *realRet = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:ret];
    [realRet stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    return realRet;
}
```

Comment: Oh, mybad..I should have mentioned that scrambBase20 is an integer array.

Comment: The other answer is working consistently...Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @AlexBedro, But you said that it is an integer array right? In that case, how will it work? You need to use count as mentioned in my answer. I didn't understand how the other answer is correct in that case. See the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/count. That would mislead people who are trying to achieve the same.

Comment: @AlexBedro, Okay understood what you meant by array. So it is c array and not using NSArray. Updated the answer, for the benefit of anyone looking for the same.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I wasn't clear about that. I'm still new to Xcode and forgot that there was a difference between the two.

Would you mind looking at my new problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795042/converting-java-to-obejctive-c-android-to-ios

Comment: @AlexBedro, I will check it. Just to let you know that the actual way to find count of items in c array is `((sizeof scrambBase20) / (sizeof int))` and not `(sizeof scrambBase20)`. Since `(sizeof int)` is returning 1 you might have got it correctly, but actually this is how it is done.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `sizeof` incorrectly: it is *not* a replacement for `length()` of Java.

You should use `strlen(cString)` on C strings, such as strings returned by `UTF8String`, or `[str length]` on `NSString` objects.